# AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Tags: python, django

Создайте HTTP клиента, который будет принимать URL ресурса, тип метода и словарь в качестве
передаваемых данных (опциональный). Выполнять запрос с полученным методом на полученный
ресурс, передавая данные соответствующим методом, и печатать на консоль статус код, заголовки
и тело ответа.

ошибка:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\http\extra\django_api> python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001E00AEB1870>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 376, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Наран\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\http\extra\django_api\tasks\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from issues.views import IssueModelViewSet, AuthView
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\http\extra\django_api\issues\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework.decorators import action
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 16, in <module>
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 16, in <module>
    from rest_framework import exceptions, status
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\exceptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers import ReturnDict, ReturnList
  File "C:\Users\Наран\PycharmProjects\soccets\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\serializer_helpers.py", line 133, in <module>
    class BindingDict(collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

Сразу скажу, что понижал до версии 3.9, менял collections.MutableMapping на collections.abc.MutableMapping, не работает

Comment: Показанный код не имеет вообще никакого отношения к возникающей ошибке. А в ошибке очевидно видно, что запуск выполняется на версии 3.10

Comment: Ошибка возникает на стороне сервера. Соответственно, понижать версию Python нужно у сервера.

Comment: Все, теперь точно понизил версию, но все равно ошибка та же. Код ошибки обновил

Comment: Все я извиняюсь за свой тупизм, прост создал новый проект и поставил туда версию 3.8 и заработало. А вам всем все равно спасибо